# Python to exe win32crypt CryptProtectData error

Tags: python, winapi

I wrote code which is using win32crypt. When I'm running in Python IDLE there is no problem. I get all data that I need.
 But when i'm converted to .exe and executed it I didn't get any result. I get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "chromeHack.py", line 22, in
>    pywintypes.error: (998, 'CryptProtectData',
>   '\xcd\xe5\xe2\xe5\xf0\xed\xe0\xff \xef\xee\xef\xfb\xf2\xea\xe0
>   \xe4\xee\xf1\xf2\xf3\xef\xe0 \xea \xe0\xe4\xf0\xe5\xf1\xf3
>   \xef\xe0\xec\xff\xf2\xe8.')

Line 22 is

```
password = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(raw[2])[1]
fileOut.write(password + '\n')
```

.exe can't use windows password to decrypt data. I tried to run as administrator but same result.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run in system command(windows?cmd:shell) to test the code before changing the code to exe.

The result told you that you have a wrong returned value after using the win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData.

the correct usage:
[win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32crypt__CryptUnprotectData_meth.html)